# dotenv files with mocha in a script line

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, dotenv

I would like to have my contract.env file with environmental varaibles loaded into a mocha test.

I tried the following but it doesn't seem to want to load:

```
npx cross-env dotenv_config_path=./contract.env mocha --require dotenv-extended/config "_build/test/contract/**/*.consumer.spec.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked:

```
npx dotenv-extended --path=contract.env mocha "_build/test/contract/**/*.consumer.spec.js"
```